# which comes first: A or B? "concerning event A, ... to the effect event B has come"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

The sentence is

> Concerning **starting of event A**, do not be quickly shaken in mind to the effect that **event
> B has already started**

Is there only one unambiguous parsing of this sentence concerning the order of events A, B?

I've convinced myself that **event B** starts first then **event A** starts but I want to be able to explain to someone why this sentence unambiguously states this.

**QUESTION**

How do I rigorously prove that the structure of this sentence states that **event B starts** first then **event A starts**.

Comment: Your "sentence" isn't really "English" at all, so there's not much point iin trying to parse it.

Comment: ...but the fact that the initial adverbial *concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ* refers to a ***future*** event has no bearing on the fact that readers are urged not to be alarmed by (present or future) communications claiming that The Second Coming has in fact already happened (or ***is*** happening now, or ***will*** happen tomorrow, or whenever). We can infer nothing about the sequence of those two events from the syntactic structure itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your example verse can, for the purposes of your question, be reduced to

> 1 Now concerning the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ .. don’t be ..alarmed, by [being told] that the day of the Lord has come.

And more clearly:

1 I’m going to talk about Jesus’s return. Don’t worry if anyone tells you that He has arrived.

The speaker is telling the crowd what he is going to talk about – He then speaks about it.

There is nothing complex or ambiguous about it.

Comment: What is the timing relationship between event A and event B? Which comes first? `the coming` or `the day of the Lord`?

Comment: Event A and event B are *the same event*. Which hasn't happened (yet! :) anyway, but nothing in any of these alternatives gives any indication as to whether either the first OR  the second reference to that event presupposes it's a Past, Present, or Future event. That's theology, not syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingers how are you concluding these two events are the same? Are you inserting your interpretation to conclude this? Event A = `the coming`, event B = `day of the Lord` which is a period of time.

Comment: I removed the part that's causing confusion. Please base your answer on my new question.

Comment: I'm not a theologian, but I take it for granted "the [second] coming" and "the day off the lord" refer to the same thing - Christ being resurrected.